# Elastic search split data based on condition

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created a es index to store millions of rows. The application is likely to grow to store more number of rows.

Is there a way to shrad the index based on a particular condition.

ie; I want to store data in a different node based on a particular condition.

Comment: Are you not happy with the Elasticsearch algorithm for automatically sharding your data?

Comment: What is the algorithm it uses? Can you refer me any document? I want to shard based on the region..ex:- EAST, WEST..etc

Comment: I suppose my query is "why do you care" - Elasticsearch will shard and balance your query load between all shards/replicas as needed on your nodes. Are you doing WAN-replication?

Comment: Thanks. I thought i have to explicitly mention the condition to partition similar to rdbms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually "answer" the question, see here for information on the sharding algorithm

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/routing-value.html

And how to change the routing

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/mapping-routing-field.html